# iOS7 : Display a popover on left to right swipe

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

How do I display a popover  when I swipe from left to right( right side area of the screen) in iOS7? I already handle UISwipeGestureRecognizer ..only thing is determine the position of the screen (right side of the screen) and display the popover.. any piece of code snippet would be really helpful... thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be a UIPopoverController?  What are you going to anchor it too?

Comment: I think you need the UIPanRecognizer instead of UISwipeRecognizer. The latter can't monitor coordinates of touches continuously.

Comment: @bbarnhart Basically, I would like to display some live statistics of an operation whenever i wish to...

@ malex Thanks.. let me try UIPanRecognizer

Comment: Why not just display in a UIView over the current content?